# having issues creating laptop wifi hotspot

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, hotspot

I have created a wifi hotspot on my work laptop (hp probook 640 g1) I started the hosted network and in the network and sharing page I could see the ssid 'hotSpot1' under the wireless network connection 2 (WNC2) icon. I also could see the ssid in the currently connected to part of the available networks page when selecting the bottom right hand corner bars. i.e.

currently connected to:

workcompany.com internet access

hotspot1 No internet access

However when I share the wireless network connection (WNC) that the workcompany.com is connected to with hotspot1. The ssid is changed to workcompany.com. so both WNC and WNC2 ssid's are displaying workcompany.com.

I have also lost the ssid in the 'currently connected to' section as well it now displays:

currently connected to:

workcompany.com internet access

When I look for hotspot1 from my mobile device I cannot find it. Anybody got any clues. Please help.

p.s. the workcompany.com internet is a domain (if it helps)

Comment: May be this will help http://wifihnc.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I installed the app on my work laptop and started the application. However although i could see 'hotspot1' from another device, on the work laptop both WNC & WNC2 were both under the work domain network. wnc2 should be separate and be public. On another device i connected to the hotspot1 wifi signal and it says it was connected but there is a amber warning signal saying not internet connection.

Comment: After you successfully created a hotspot. Can you try the internet connection sharing tab of internet connected adapter. To share internet with newly created hotspot?

Comment: I just read your question again. Does your laptop WiFi adapter support acting as wifi repeater? Maybe what you are trying is not possible due to hardware limitation. You can try sharing wired connection over WiFi.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It might be a problem with the work wifi. At home i use wifi and both wnc and wnc2 are separate and i can connect multiple devices to hotspot1 and use the internet without any problems. In work however both wnc & wnc2 are forced together under the work domain network after sharing is enabled. I can see hotspot1 and connect to it using wifihnc app but its says no internet access. Is there a way to stop work wifi from forcing both wnc & wnc2 merging under the work network and make wnc2 separate and public?.

Comment: Probably someone else will have to answer it. I never used it as repeater.

Comment: On a later thought. Are you corporate policies are not restricting your devices from accessing internet? As virtual hotspot has different ip, gateway and other settings

Comment: You can try a workaround. Run a proxy on your laptop. And use this to access internet from other devices connected to laptop

Comment: thanks, on your last comment, how can i do this,my knowledge of networking is limited. Furthermore i thought a wifi hotspot is independent of the source internet connection. i.e. the connection is split but the new hotspot has its own policies and not controlled by work wifi.

Comment: Generally corporate networks require you to access internet through a corporate proxy. Which is configured automatically when a computer connects to it. Same does not happen when a device connects to your hotspot. To check which proxy is being used open "internet options" goto connections tab. Open proxy for LAN connections setting and check.

Comment: Regarding running your local proxy. Download fiddler (or anything more simple which you know of) and run it. Change it settings to listen on all interfaces and allow remote devices to connect to it. Then put in fiddler proxy details in the devices your are trying to access internet from.  More details search for "Android configure fiddler"

Comment: Please note that I am typing all the above from my phone. I don't have access to my machine for some days. So not everything may be accurate too the point. As I wrote it from memory.

Comment: Also make sure you're not breaking any corporate policies as it may lead to termination. You have been warned

Comment: I tired it out today and it worked. By adding the proxy settings to the browser i was able to access the internet. However is it possible to increase the speed.? The source internet doesn't go under 72mbps. The hotspot fluctuates between 5 - 30mbps.

Comment: If you are using Fiddler ensure "Stream" toggle is selected.

Comment: what if you are not using fiddler